# Is the term 4koma a generic term?

Tags: terminology

I know the term 4koma only from the *.hack* series, in which it normally relates to the parody manga *.hack//4koma*, and it's also the title of the bonus videos unlocked in *.hack//G.U.* on the desktop.

However, I have seen the term 4koma used in other places, so I am wondering if the term 4koma is a generic term used to describe something, and if so, what it actually means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**4koma** (pronounced **yonkoma**) is a Japanese word meaning "4-panel"<sup>1</sup>, and refers to a type of manga which is formatted as a series of four vertically-stacked panels. This term is used in contrast with "regular" (non-4koma) manga, which do not typically adhere to a rigid panel structure.<sup>2</sup>

Here is an example from one very long-running (and famous in Japan) 4koma manga, *Sazae-san*:<sup>3</sup>

[image: Sazae-san 4koma strip from July 4, 1962]

Some of the most famous 4koma manga among Western audiences are *Azumanga Daioh*, *Lucky Star*, *Hetalia*, and *K-ON*. As this list suggests, the 4koma format is heavily populated by gag comedy manga.

---

<sup>1</sup> from 四 *yon* "four" + 齣 *koma* "scene, frame, panel"; usually written 四コマ today.

<sup>2</sup> Think of 4koma as being sort of like your bog-standard weekday newspaper cartoons (at least in the US) in that sense - 3 or 4 panels, and no real freedom as to how to use the space available.

<sup>3</sup> Note that most 4koma these days have narrower panels (usually square), allowing two 4koma to be printed side-by-side on paper with a standard A or B aspect ratio